# InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement Angular 5

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do autocomplete for an address using the google mapsAPI in my app, but I keep getting the "InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement" error. Below are the things I have tried

html input inside of a form. As you can see I tried the focus trick and it didn't work either.

```
 <input id="address" type="text" name="address" #address="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="markersService.selectedMarker.address" placeholder="Address" 
    autocorrect="off"
    autocapitalize="off"
    spellcheck="off"
    class="inputFields"
    required
    (focus)="autocompleteSearch()"/>
```

.ts file

```
 //I implemented this in an app with Angular 4 and it worked, now with Angular5 it' doesn't
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.autocompleteSearch();
 }


  autocompleteSearch() {
    /*
    I tried this trick based on some answers I saw in different places, but it didn't work
    var addressInput = document.getElementById('address').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    of course I was passing this in the code below instead of the addressElement
    */
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(
      ()=>{
        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.addressElement.nativeElement, { types:["address"]});
        autocomplete.addListener('places_changed', ()=> {
          this.ngZone.run(()=> {
            let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

            if(place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
              return;
            }
          });
        })
      }
    )
  }
```

I tried 4 different things, no luck to get this to work

Comment: Can we see the declaration for `addressElement`? Also, is the input element inside an `ngFor` loop or inside an ancestor with an `ngIf` condition?

Comment: As for the "trick", you could try: `const addressInput = document.getElementById('address');`, and replace `this.addressElement.nativeElement` with `addressInput` (although using `document.getElementById` is not the Angular way to access elements).

Comment: @ConnorsFan no, they are not inside of an ngIf or ngFor. You are right, that's not a proper angular way to do it, but I was determinated to try everything lol. The const addressInput = document.getElementById('address'); didn't work. I get an error on VS code saying "Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLInputElement'.
  Property 'accept' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'."

Comment: Please show the declaration of `addressElement`, that is the most important. For the "trick", try with: `const addressInput = document.getElementById('address') as HTMLInputElement;`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan `@ViewChild ('address') public addressElement: ElementRef;` Now, with `const addressInput = document.getElementById('address') as HTMLInputElement;` I don't get the original error, but the autocomplete doesn't work and I don't see more error in the console

Comment: @ConnorsFan I get this warning, but no error. Could this be the cause why the autocomplete is not working? `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help`

Comment: @ConnorsFan so i dig it down to being working outside the modal, in the modal it doesn't work

Comment: The template variable `#address` is tied to `ngModel`. You should define another one, like `#address1`, in the input element, and use that one in `@ViewChild('address1')`. That should work (instead of using `document.getElementById`). I am not sure that it will help for the other problems though.

Comment: @ConnorsFan so maybe that was part of the fix. I also noticed the autocomplete has behind the modal so I added `.pac-container {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
' and that made it appear on top of the modal. Thanks so much man!! If you want, post it as an answer so I can make it the correct answer and you get some points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template reference variable `#address` is tied to `ngModel`. You could define another one, like `#address1`:

```
<input #address1 #address="ngModel" ... >
```

and use it to access the element in code:

```
@ViewChild('address1') public addressElement: ElementRef;

...

let inputElement = this.addressElement.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
```